# How to Order mysql rows by alphabet

Tags: mysql

I Have:

```
 ----------------------------
| ID          |  Workout     |
|_____________|______________|
| 1           |What Chest    |
| 2           |Me self it's  |
| 3           |End workout   |
_____________________________
```

Basically I've a `like` query which is:

```
SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE wourkout LIKE '%e%'
```

Now I need to order found rows based on letter `e` first in rows.
To be precise It should order it like:

```
 ----------------------------
| ID          |  Workout     |
|_____________|______________|
| 1           |End Workout   |
| 2           |Me self it's  |
| 3           |What Chest    |
_____________________________
```

As you can see my `End workout` row contains the letter `e` before other rows do.

Comment: use union all clause

Comment: See substring_index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM db.table
WHERE workout LIKE '%e%'
ORDER BY INSTR(workout, _utf8'e') ASC
```

As long as `workout` is not a binary string, `INSTR` will return the position of the first `"e"` (or `E`) in `workout`; `1` for the beginning, `2` for second place...